# How to insert a table name from the result of another table

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, inner-join, database-schema

I have a table in mysql called "tables" and this table contains the name of all tables names and tables ids.

Schema from tables:
[image]

I need to do a INNER JOIN of this table and replace the values `{table}` and `{column_id}`

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM attributes_categories AS ac

    INNER JOIN attributes_codes AS aco ON aco.id_attribute_code = 
        ac.attributes_codes_id_attribute_code

    INNER JOIN {$table} AS b
    LEFT JOIN translations AS t ON t.id = b.{$column_id}
```

I'm trying something like this, BUT, I can't replace the "INNER JOIN {$table}", because I can't insert the result in place of the table name:

```sql
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM attributes_categories AS ac

    INNER JOIN attributes_codes AS aco ON aco.id_attribute_code = 
       ac.attributes_codes_id_attribute_code

    INNER JOIN tables AS tab ON tab.id_table = ac.tables_id_table

    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ON TABLE_NAME = tab.table

    INNER JOIN tab.table AS b
    LEFT JOIN translations AS t ON t.id = b.column_id

    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='knskjhpumw1'
```

The result is:

```
Mensagens do MySQL :

#1146 - Tabela 'tab.table' does not exist
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a Stored Procedure, you can construct a query with `CONCAT()` (etc) and "execute" it.  With such you can 'easily' insert a dynamic table name (etc).

Another approach is to construct the SQL in your client code, such as PHP or Java.